# What to do with a damaged Bilva tree at home?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, plants

I have an old Bilva tree at my home and it got damaged after Varda cyclone and it is not growing after that. I have tried every thing to restore it but all methods failed.

Are there any instructions from scriptures regarding whether one should keep the damaged tree as it is in the home or how to deal with it (or dispose it in case it's not ok to keep it) or plant a new one?

Comment: Hi! This question comes under personal advice question and has nothing to do with Hinduism religion. You should post it on [gardening.se] after reading their help center page.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It is not off-topic. Bilva, Tulasi are holy plants and there may be some methods prescribed in scriptures to remove damaged plants since they are considered as holy.

Comment: @TheDestroyer It is off-topic. Plants like Tulasi, Bilva etc., are auspicious but how to plant them, remove them etc., is gardening stuff and it is related to other site. The question is advice about  a tree "what to do can I remove and plant a new one or leave it as it is". We don't give personal advices and this is least of it Gardening advice.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma These plants are not normal plants but holy plants. There are some rules while sowing them, doing pooja and even uprooting or removing them. These are not advices but scriptural injunctions. One must follow scriptures when dealing with holy plants such as Tulasi or Bilva. But question tone looks like personal advice question but this question doesn't go to Gardening SE.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I disagree with the suggestion that it is not off topic. If the question was posed something like, "Is it forbidden to keep a damaged bilva plant?" or something similar to that, then it would probably be on topic. But as it is, the question is just asking for advice on whether to keep a plant at home or get rid of it. It needs a small edit, but only the OP can make those changes.

Comment: @BhargavRao Right now it looks like personal advice which is off-topic. But this question doesn't go to gardening SE.  But there are proper methods in Scriptures to dispose holy plants like Tulasi or Bilva. If question is edited , this can be made on-topic. Disposal methods of holy plants are on-topic and these questions belong to Hinduism SE.

Comment: Dear @Aham Brahmasmi,  your question currently looks like an advice seeking question which is off-topic for our site. You can [edit] your question and reword asking for instructions for disposal of plant or replanting the new plant according to scriptures. So, that we can reopen the question.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yup, agree with that. It certainly isn't on topic on Gardening. The post as such is off topic everywhere.

Comment: From where are you coming?